# Jedi-vim + YCM issue

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme, jedi-vim

I have a issue with hints showed by Jedi VIM. Here is how it looks like:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC9nd.png)

Here are my .vimrc settings:

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py"
let g:ycm_python_binary_path = "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/bin/python"
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion=[]
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion=[]
set completeopt-=preview

" Jedi Python autocomplete
let g:ycm_filetype_specific_completion_to_disable = { 'python' : 1 }
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = { 'python' : 1 }

let g:jedi#show_call_signatures_delay = 1
let g:jedi#auto_initialization = 1
let g:jedi#auto_vim_configuration = 1
let g:jedi#use_tabs_not_buffers = 1
let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 1
let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 1
let g:jedi#completions_enabled = 1
let g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "1"
let g:jedi#goto_command = "<leader>d"
let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = "<leader>g"
let g:jedi#goto_definitions_command = ""
let g:jedi#documentation_command = "K"
let g:jedi#usages_command = "<leader>n"
let g:jedi#completions_command = "<C-Space>"
let g:jedi#rename_command = "<leader>r"
autocmd FileType python setlocal completeopt-=preview
```

I believe there is something wrong with Jedi-VIM/YCM configuration. I tried to disable/enable different options for both YCM and JediVIM, but it only goes two ways: either it shows call signatures twice, or it doesn't show call signatures at all.

Please advice.

Comment: What do you mean by it's shown twice?

Comment: @DaveHalter, take a loot at the image. http://i.stack.imgur.com/NC9nd.png Hint with arguments is shown twice.

Comment: Wow, no idea how this happened. You can also show the call signatures in a different place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouCompleteMe comes with Jedi integration through [JediHTTP](https://github.com/vheon/JediHTTP). It is not compatible with `jedi-vim`, hence the behavior you're seeing. I'd recommend uninstalling `jedi-vim`.